# ios7 beta on ipod touch 4 - how to intsall

Tags: installation, ipod-touch, beta, ios7

the apple developer newsletter states:

> iOS 7 beta 2 for iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch...

but how to install iOS7 on ipod touch 4? Which image should i use? 
Available for the ipod touch is only the image für the 5th generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 7 can only be installed on iPod 5.

Comment: damn... just bought an iPod touch 4 just for the iOS7 beta testing. The devil is in the details.

Comment: That makes this question so important!

Comment: @idan, actually, that's why it's important to read the release notes. This question is superfluous.